# Apex Class Editing - Class name is already in use or has been previously used

Tags: salesforce, apex

I am learning Salesforce and am working on the following Trailhead unit:
https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/identity_external/identity_external_social?trail_id=identity

(Setting up a social sign on for the sandbox environment)

1. I make an authenicated provider (google) by going to setup -> auth -> auth providers
2. For the registration handle I click 'Let salesforce create an automatic registration handler'
3. I then go to setup -> find-> apex classes, find the newly created apex class. I delete the code that is in the apex class and insert the code that is available here:

https://github.com/salesforceidentity/IdentityTrail-Module3/blob/master/Module3RegistrationHandler.cls

According to trailhead, the code should be active, and the social sign on for google should now work. However, when I go to save it, I get the following message:

"   Error: Class name is already in use or has been previously used "

**So, how do I save my edits to Apex?**
**What is this error and why am I getting it?**

I'm assuming then that when edit the text inside an apex class, and go to save, that it's not over-writing the current apex class; rather, that it's trying to make a separate instance of the same class with the same name, and is throwing an error. I would appreciate any assistance on to how I can successfully edit this APEX class!

Answer (score 0):

Ok - so I checked, and it looks like when I had previously saved one of these apex classes, the class name in the code is module3registrationhandler and it auto created another class in the drop down list. so when I tried again to save it from the autocreatedhandler, it said that you had previously done this. Error found. Salesforce rejects duplicates.